# How to name an item in a pre-filled chest

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want have the item in the chest (the dye) to have a custom name, I have tried very hard to do so.

Here is what I have so far (it works but I need the item to have a name as said before):

```
/give @p chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:dye,Damage:2,Count:1}]}}
```

Also I need the answer in 1.12

Here are things I tried but failed:

```
/give @p chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:dye,Damage:2,Count:1,disp‌​lay:{Name:"Name of item"}}]}}
```

and

```
/give @p chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[Slot:0,id:dye,Damage:2,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Name of item"}}]}}
```

Comment: What's not happening? What does the error (if any) say?

Comment: Well I tried add this to the command but it wouldn't work `/give @p chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:dye,Damage:2,Count:1,display:{Name="Name of item"}}]}}`

Comment: Again, is this giving you an error?

Comment: No! The command above does work

Comment: You should be adding your attempt into your question, not as just a comment; as it is, it doesn't look like you've actually tried to add a name to your command.

Comment: why would I put it in there if I know it doesn't work?

Comment: So that we know what you've tried, so we can point out what went wrong.  And so we see you've tried to solve it yourself, which readers will respond to better than just asking us to do it for you.

Comment: Understandable Have a nice day

Comment: The Minecraft tag should be part of this question, for proper organization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that you would put within the data tag of a `/give` command…

```
/give @p dye 1 2 {display:{Name:"Bob"}}
```

…is stored within the "tag" of an item, like so:

```
/give @p chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:dye,Damage:2,Count:1, tag:{display:{Name:"Bob"}} }]}}
```

Comment: hmm this does not work I put it in minecraft and it had an error. Did it work for you?

Comment: /give @p chest 1 0 {BlockEntityTag:{Items:[{Slot:0,id:dye,Damage:2,Count:1,tag:{display:{Name:"Bob"}}}]}}

Is correct, SB forgot that Items is a list of compounds.

Comment: thanks Pepijn I just wish you submitted this as a answer so I could check it

Comment: I edited it in. To be able save, I had to change at least 6 characters, so I changed the quote formatting to a code formatting, but that didn't work, because there was an empty line missing, so now the formatting is wrong, but I can't edit it until my previous edit was reviewed. Great. The mobile page really needs a preview function.

Comment: Oh sorry about leaving out the list part. I got so focused on explaining where the tag comes from I forgot to double check my command